# java.lang.VerifyError thrown when I stop my application

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring jar in my application. When i stop my application forcefully while its instance is still runnning, i get java.lang.VerifyError.
Take a look at this:

`2014-03-18 15:29:26,941 ERROR [localhost-startStop-2] ? - Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator' threw an exception
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils, method: convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible signature: (Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;)Lorg/springframework/dao/DataAccessException;) Wrong return type in function
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)`

What i studied was:
   It might be because the code was compiled in other environment and now the reference is to another environment (Might be the spring jar is updated and possibly the return type has been altered)

But what i need is the root cause of this issue.

Comment: What does `(Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;)Lorg/springframework/dao/DataAccessException;` mean?

Answer (score 0):

The method `convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible` tries to convert JPA Exceptions into the Spring equivalent Exception. These exceptions can be found in spring-orm (where you can find EntityManagerFactoryUtils itself) and in spring-tx. Be sure your project includes both of them. Then you will can check what actually happens when you stops the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is spring-tx a package or jar? And what it has to do with my issue.
My prev version of application was running well with same configurations and jars

Comment: It's the Spring Transaction support module: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html.  It contains DataAccessException class, so you need it in your classpath. But since I don't know the changes you made in your app from a version to another, I can't say what is causing this issue.